# How to pass a templated class its own class as default template type?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a problem where I want to pass the class itself as default template of itself as in:

```
template<typename dataType, typename nodeType = node<dataType> >
class node
{
  ...
}
```

`clang` is giving the following error:

```
error: unknown type name 'node'
```

Comment: C++ parsers aren't happy ~ what's the use of that? What are  you trying to accomplish aside from asking "is this possible at all" ?

Comment: What do you actually want to solve with this construct? It's not possible as mentioned.

Comment: @tobi303 there might be another way to implement this, can't it be implemented in some another manner??

Comment: @user3712270 Have you taken a look at CRTP? It's not what you had in mind but might solve your issue

Comment: @MarcoA. If i can't pass it as default then i will have to pass it explicitly and there goes the abstraction..

Comment: Just consider how templates get implemented by the compiler. How should the compiler implement this class, when it is parametrized with its own type? You really should tell what you actually want to acomplish and try to find a different solution

Comment: I agree with tobi, this is an XY problem

Comment: @MarcoA. Thnx, CRTP was good enough and sorry for the vagueness of the question.

Comment: @user3712270 No problem, I'm not spasmodically seeking rep :) Anyway describe your problem better next time, rather than describing your attempted solution (there might be a better one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) for this:

```
template <class Node_type>
class BaseNode
{
    //Common logic for nodes here
};

template <class Data_type>
class Node : public BaseNode< Node<Data_type> >
{
    ...
}
```